# Can I use Apache Camel with Jax-ws implementation in application server (e. WAS, WLS) without CXF or Axis2?

Tags: apache-camel

I dont want to use Axis2 or CXF with Camel. Is it possible to configure camel with JAX-WS reference implementation or weblogic application server or websphere application server or tomcat + jax-ws refrence implementation?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Camel provides 2 web services components out of the box: camel-cxf and camel-spring-ws. For any other web service integration just use plain java. From any Java code, you can send a message to Camel using the ProducerTemplate. Then that way you can bridge the JAX-WS of the application server with Camel. We used to have an old example at Apache Camel that showed how to integrate Axis 1.4 with Camel, but that examples has been removed as part of cleanup recently.

Answer (score 1):

As far as I know that is not possible. The camel-axis and camel-cxf components are directly using the cxf and axis classes. You could use the SoapDataFormat but this is just for simple cases and not a full stack.